Conditional probability and how to calculate it
I have $y_1,y_2,y_3, y_4$ i.i.d.  $U[0;1]$. I want to calculate $P(2y_2-y_3>y_1,2y_3-y_2>y_4)$. It looks like cumulative function of vector $(y_1,y_4)$, so and as $y_1$ and $y_4$ are independent, I want to fator it on $F_{y_1}(2y_2-y_3)*F_{y_4}(2y_3-y_2)$, but there are random variables in the argument. So, there is the first question: may I factor it and then use formula of total probability, or should I use total probability formula first?
The second question is about how to calculate it. In both variants we will integrate functions that can be more than 1 or less than 0 ($\int_0^1\int_0^1 (2y_2-y_3)(2y_3-y_2)dy_3dy_2$ or $\int_0^1\int_0^1(2y_2-y_3)dy_3dy_2*\int_0^1\int_0^1(2y_3-y_2)dy_3dy_2$), how to deal with it?

In what way is this conditional probability? What is "it" that you want to factor on a formula, and why that formula? Why would you want to integrate those integrals? I recommend you edit the question to show more of how you are thinking about this, because it is not clear.

It is just a volume of a certain subset of a 4 dimensional unit cube

You want to integrate the product of the CDF, rather than the product of the integrals of the CDF.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(y_1<2y_2-y_3,y_4<2y_3-y_2)&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 F_{y_1}(2y_2-y_3)F_{y_4}(2y_3-y_2)\,\mathrm d y_3\,\mathrm d y_2\end{align}$$
You also need to ascertain where the CDF lie between $0$ and $1$, and where they are capped at $1$ (or $0$).
$$\begin{align}F_{y_1}(2y_2-y_3) &= (2y_2-y_3)\mathbf 1_{0<(2y_2-y_3)<1}+\mathbf 1_{1\leq (2y_2-y_3)}\\[2ex]F_{y_4}(2y_3-y_2) &= (2y_3-y_2)\mathbf 1_{0<(2y_3-y_2)<1}+\mathbf 1_{1\leq (2y_3-y_2)}\end{align}$$

Thank you very much!
